# Alternative to use HttpContext in System.Web for Owin

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, owin, katana

ASP.NET authentication is now based on OWIN middleware that can be used on any OWIN-based host. ASP.NET Identity **does not have any dependency on System.Web**.

I have an AuthorizeAttribute filter where I need to get the current user and add some properties to be retrieved later by action controllers.

The problem is that I have to use the HttpContext which belongs to System.Web. Is there any alternative of HttpContext for Owin?

```cs
public class WebApiAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute 
{
    public override async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);

        Guid userId = new Guid(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId());

        ApplicationUserManager manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new ApplicationUserStore(new ApplicationDbContext())) { PasswordHasher = new CustomPasswordHasher() };
        ApplicationUser user = await manager.FindByIdAsync(userId);

        actionContext.Request.Properties.Add("userId", user.LegacyUserId);
    }
}
```

Note: I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23814265/what-to-use-instead-of-httpcontext-when-using-owin-without-system-web), which seems a duplicate, but asks for a solution working for NancyFx project, which is not valid for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This article](http://brockallen.com/2013/10/27/host-authentication-and-web-api-with-owin-and-active-vs-passive-authentication-middleware/) gives me the solution:

> Web API 2 introduced a new
>   RequestContext class that contains a Principal property. This is now
>   the proper location to look for the identity of the caller. This
>   replaces the prior mechanisms of Thread.CurrentPrincipal and/or
>   HttpContext.User. This is also what you would assign to if you are
>   writing code to authenticate the caller in Web API.

So just modifying the line:

```
Guid userId = new Guid(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

by

```
Guid userId = new Guid(actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.GetUserId());
```

now, the reference to System.Web is not needed anymore.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [OwinRequestScopeContext](https://github.com/neuecc/OwinRequestScopeContext/). Which is doing exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: +1 for good solution. What I understood is that with OWIN there's no place for Auhtorization filters anymore.

Comment: @Freerider after reading [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn781361.aspx) It seems Authorization Filter is still the way to go.

Comment: @Morio I agree with you. Thanks for posting.

Comment: OwinRequestScopeContext.Current is null always. Please help.

Comment: Also null for me, pretty sure I wired it up correctly in startup too, oh well it was worth a shot.

Answer (score 3):

After reading [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn781361.aspx). It seems to me that extending AuthorizeAttribute is still the way to go. 
However, since HttpContext is IIS based, we want to avoid using it from now on.

There is a HttpActionContext got passed in. Then we could use

```
actionContext.Request.GetRequestContext().Principal.Identity
```

or

```
actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity
```

OR

`actionContext.Request.GetOwinContext().Request.User.Identity`
to get to the identity. All three will get you the same identity object.

and yes, OwinContext is available this way too.