# OWIN equivalent to HttpContext.Application Property

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, owin

I want to find an equivalent to the HttpContext.Application Property but using OWIN. I'm not looking for the equivalent of HttpContext in OWIN because I already know what is it, I need to know what's the exactly equivalent of the Application property.

What I want to do is to create an object at the startup, use it on some request to Web API without recreating the object again so I want to have it in memory.

I'm using:
- .Net 4.5
- ASP.NET Web API 2.2
- Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb 3.0.1

I've searched on Google and StackOverflow and found that I should use the     `CreatePerOwinContext` method but I don't know how to get the value I set into the context when I get requests from the clients on Web API.

In the old ASP.NET host I used to use this:

var myVariable = HttpContext.Application["MyVariable"]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternative to use HttpContext in System.Web for Owin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24572794/alternative-to-use-httpcontext-in-system-web-for-owin)

Comment: @2kay thank you but that question doesn't solve my question. I'm asking for an equivalent to the `HttpContext.Application` and how to get the value from it usin OWIN and the question you are talking about just say how to use it for authentication.

Answer (score 2):

If you used `CreatePerOwinContext` to create the instance `myVariable` of type `myType` then you should be able to use something like the following:

```
HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<MyType>()
```

The return will  be `myVariable` or the default return value if not present.

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn270631(v=vs.113).aspx

Note however, that `CreatePerOwinContext` is still creating a new instance of the specified object per request, so you will need to figure out a way to pass your in-memory instance of `MyType` as part of the static `Create` method called by `CreatePerOwinContext`.

Or, you could set a public instance on the `WebApiApplication` class in `Global.asax` during the call to `Application_Start()` and then just grab it when needed, but that's a little... eew.

Comment: It seems that CreatePerOwinContext is not the better solution for what I need so I will look for another solution. But I want to ask you something, HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<MyType>() needs a key parameter but when creating the CreatePerOwinContext it doesn't ask for the key, just for a creating method so where can I set the key? Thanks.

Comment: `CreatePerOwinContext` is used with a static method which returns an instance of the type you are looking for. For an example, look at how the basic ASP.NET project with Identity uses `CreatePerOwinContext` in `Startup_Auth`, and then find the static `Create` method defined on any of `ApplicationDbContext` or `ApplicationUserManager`