# Autofac and Web Api 2 - How to get the User (authenticated or not)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, autofac

I am having an issue with users and autofac.
I followed a guide that said to get the current user to use in your services, you must first create a wrapper class like this:

```
public class PrincipalProvider : IPrincipalProvider
{
    public IPrincipal User => HttpContext.Current?.User;
}
```

And then you need to register it as PerDependency in your module like this:

```
builder.RegisterType<PrincipalProvider>().As<IPrincipalProvider>().InstancePerDependency();
```

Then I have a simple controller:

```
private readonly IHealthCheckProvider _healthCheckProvider;

/// <summary>
/// Default constructor
/// </summary>
/// <param name="healthCheckProvider">The provider used to do health checks</param>
public HealthCheckController(IHealthCheckProvider healthCheckProvider)
{
    _healthCheckProvider = healthCheckProvider;
}

/// <summary>
/// Lists all the current services and their status details
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
[HttpGet]
[Route("")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ListAsync() => Ok(await _healthCheckProvider.ListAsync());
```

The healthcheck provider has the **principal provider** injected into it and the list method tries to get the current user:

```
private readonly CormarConfig _config;
private readonly IHealthCheckService _healthCheckService;
private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

private readonly Lazy<IPrincipalProvider> _principalProvider;

public HealthCheckProvider(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, CormarConfig config, IHealthCheckService healthCheckService, Lazy<IPrincipalProvider> principalProvider)
{
    _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    _config = config;
    _healthCheckService = healthCheckService;

    _principalProvider = principalProvider;
}

public async Task<IList<HealthCheck>> ListAsync()
{
    var models = await _healthCheckService.List().ToListAsync();
    var user = _principalProvider.Value.User;
    return models;
}
```

The problem I have is that the **user** is always null.
Does anyone know how I can solve this?

And just for reference sake, here is my config method in the **StartupConfig.cs** class:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{

    // Cors must be first, or it will not work
    app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB");

    // Get our configuration
    var config = new HttpConfiguration();
    var container = ConfigureInversionOfControl(app, config);
    var scope = config.DependencyResolver.GetRootLifetimeScope();
    var serverOptions = ConfigureOAuthTokenGeneration(app, scope);

    // Configur our application
    ConfigureOAuthTokenConsumption(app);
    ConfigureWebApi(config, scope);

    // Register the Autofac middleware FIRST. This also adds
    // Autofac-injected middleware registered with the container.
    app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
    app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);
    app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(serverOptions);
    app.UseWebApi(config);
}
```

I don't think anything is wrong in there, but you never know.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on your `public IPrincipal User => HttpContext.Current?.User;` line and see what's null etc, or even if it is being hit.

Do you ever build your container?  I can't see it in your code sample.

Comment: the context seems to be always null. Yeah I do build, it's later on. I have stripped out most of the code to make things simpler

Comment: Are you using OWIN hosting? I don't believe `HttpContext.Current` is what you want to use if you are.  If you're OWIN-hosted, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24572864/68432

Comment: r3plica, did you get this working?

Comment: Not really, no. It works as long as the service that I inject this into is injected into a controller. A nested service doesn't have access to the HttpContext.

Comment: Looking at it again, httpcontext.current is threadstatic and you're accessing it directly after an "await" call (await _healthCheckService.List().ToListAsync();).  Try making that line synchronous (or just remove or reorder the lines to test)....?